# HTML Binding from pipe in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-pipe

```
transform(value, type, headerSelectArray = [], valueToBeSelected, hasAction = false, functionName) {
        try {
            if (type === '_field') {
                return value;
            } else if (type === '_select_attribute') {
                let options;
                options = (`<select ` + `(click)="updateStatus()"` + `>`);
                headerSelectArray.forEach(element => {
                    options += `<option value="` + element.key + `" selected="` + (element.key === valueToBeSelected) + `" >` + element.label + `</option>`;
                });
                options += `</select>`;
                return this.sanatize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(options);
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error--', e);
        }
    }
```

This is my pipe function which returns html content based on some conditions. I am binding the data using the innerHtml property in my component.html section.

The issue I am facing is that the Click event is not binded with html.
[Click here](https://ibb.co/q1qmBCr)

Comment: It seems like you need to somehow force angular for rendering. It is not rendering your thing. You can check https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: @canbax Is that related to change detection or else related to binding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this piece of code in your **ngAfterViewChecked()** function

```
ngAfterViewChecked (){
 if(this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-select')){
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-select').addEventListener('click', this. updateStatus.bind(this));
 }
}
```

and in your constructor

```
 constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef){ }
```

and modify your code by adding an id attribute to your select

```
 transform(value, type, headerSelectArray = [], valueToBeSelected, hasAction = false, functionName) {
    try {
        if (type === '_field') {
            return value;
        } else if (type === '_select_attribute') {
            let options;
            options = (`<select class=`"my-select"` ` + `(change)="updateStatus()"` + `>`);
            headerSelectArray.forEach(element => {
                options += `<option value="` + element.key + `" selected="` + (element.key === valueToBeSelected) + `" >` + element.label + `</option>`;
            });
            options += `</select>`;
            return this.sanatize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(options);
        }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error--', e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I my case the html part will be in loop, so I can't give a constant Id

Comment: I've updated my answer appropriately. You can use a dummy css class for getting the element using query selector and bind the click attribute to the element even if in a loop.

Comment: Great buddy, It helped

Comment: Still facing an issue, onChange works only for the first element of the loop

Comment: I changed the concept. Instead of loading from pipe, I used If else in my html template

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to render HTML based on some parameters, right? In Angular, components do exactly that, and you shouldn't hack pipes to do that. Pipes are to create simple text values from data, see https://angular.io/guide/pipes

So just take the parameters that you pass in to your pipe, **create a component instead of the pipe, and pass those params to the new component**.

Also, whenever you manually create an html string, and then add it to the DOM via `innerHtml`, you misuse angular, the whole point of angular that you don't explicitly manipulate the DOM.

The click handler doesn't work, because the `(click)="updateStatus()` is not standard HTML and if you pass it with `innerHtml` the browser will not know what you are talking about. This click handler syntax only works inside an angular template, which you can have with a component.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the @component set   `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`

```
@Component({
  selector: "component-selector",
  templateUrl: "./x.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./x.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: can you please tell me, what is the use/advantage of using encapsulation

Comment: Please refer: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html